# Datediff function in Access Database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to use Datediff function while subtracting two dates. One date is with Date and time stamp and the other with date only. How to get the difference of dates?

Here Column1 is `7/11/2017 4:24:38 PM` and Column2 is `15/12/2017` where there is no timestamp.

```
DateDiff("d",[Column1],[Column2])
```

Comment: Obviously depends on what type of db you're using but here are the docs for mysql's DATEDIFF https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff. This function in mysql will work with both date and date-and-time objects

Comment: It is working If both the columns are without time stamp. Failing if one with date , one with date and time stamp.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the date column into datetime using Format function. See example below.
EDIT: since you want the difference in days and decimal point, I get the difference in hours then divide by 24.  You can be as accurate if you want by getting the difference in minutes or seconds but using a different divisor.

```
SELECT DateDiff("h",
       Now(),
       Format('04/05/2018','mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss'))/24 AS Expr1;

result: 1.125 days
```

Comment: I cannot convert the date time into date, the difference of date is expected in decimal format. i.e 2.7865 something like this

Comment: I am looking for a function which converts date into time stamp, so that my output correct. I have used "General Date" but it is not returning any difference instead it is returning null.

Comment: I updated my answer but still using format function.

Comment: if you like my answer, please upvote/accept it. thanks.